# A timer for the rocket lift off

Tags: python

i would like to have a countdown for my rocket to life off but i just cant make it decrease the number it only stays the same can someone help me?

```
print("program is writen by someone")
name = input("program is runned by")
print(name,",if you are a pilot of the project please type pilot for the next question. If you are other please type your reason/role for u being here")
x = input("what is your reason for u being here")
if x == 'pilot':
    print (name,"ok wlecome to the crew")
    h = input ("is the hatch closed? please answer closed or no")
    if h == 'closed':
        import time as t
        second = int(input ("very good please enter the needed for the countdown"))
        for i in range(second):
            print (str(second - 1)+ "second remaining \n")
        t.sleep(1)
        print ("time is up")
    else:
         print ("please check if the hatch is close")
         
else:
    y = input("are you 600meters away from the spacecraft?")
    if y == 'yes':
        print ("have a nice time watching the show")
    else:
        print("please stand back untill u are 600 meter away from the aircraft")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the loop variable and printing the same `second-1` value every time. You can use a decreasing range, e.g.:

```
for i in range(second, 0, -1):
    print(f'{i} seconds remaining')
    time.sleep(1)
```

or simply a `while`-loop:

```
while second:
    print(f'{second} seconds remaining')
    second -= 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

(Notice that `time.sleep()` is called inside the loop body)